# Имя vs название

Tags: словоупотребление

I've seen both used for both people and things.  So are they interchangeable?  What's the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In contemporary language.

**имя**:

- first name of a person (Василий, Вася; surname = фамилия)
- file name (computer engineering), names of variables in mathematics, etc.
- things in some idiomatic expressions (называть вещи своими *именами* = to call a spade a spade)
- used for naming something in someone's honour: Kirov (now Mariinsky) Theatre = Театр *имени* Кирова, and despite using the word "имя", it's actually the "название театра";
- grammatical parts of speech (*имя* существительное = noun)

In most other cases, the words **наименование** or **название** are used. Животные - *наименование* биологического вида. Тигр и лев - *названия* диких кошачьих.

While it's sometimes possible to use имя for ships or pets, that would be rather informal usage. Much more typical are *название* корабля and *кличка* собаки.

Answer (score 2):

**Definitions**

```
       act of mentioning by word is Называть,               
              and give us in result
                      |
                   (nouns)
                  Названия 
                    /  \
                   /    \
                  /      \
    имена собственные   имена нарицательные
      (proper name)       (common name)
               /            \
              /              \
      ┌───────────┐       ┌───────────┐     
         read.me             file      
         system              folder    
         Владимир            human     *
         Tokio               city      
         Рекс                dog       *   
         Победа              chip      

 * see special usage below
```

Examples:

> ```
> Атомные подводные лодки называются именами городов. 
>                                                       [«Известия»,2002.03.21]    
> Стали вырастать один за другим поселки, и их справедливо называли 
> именами первооткрывателей.
>                             [В. Писигин. Письма с Чукотки // «Октябрь», 2001]
> Карданус предлагал, «чтобы не было стыдно», славное имя «Ермака»
> отменить и кораблю присвоить название «Ледокол Э 2».
>                               [Б. Г. Островский. Адмирал Макаров (1949-1955)]
> ```

**Usage:**

```
   human, pet                                            
   ──┬───────
     │                   ┌ физрук         - Андрей Андреевич              
     │       ┌  учитель ─┤ химичка        - Алла Андреевна              
     │       │           └ трудовик       - Борис Борисович
     └ human ┤                            
             │           ┌ первоклассник  - Геннадий
             └  ученик  ─┤ второклассник  - Владимир
                         └ выпускник      - Евгений

      └─────┘ └───────┘   └─────────────┘  └─────────────────┘                   
      └─────────────────────────────────┘          имена          
                названия        

   A thing or place (in time or space). 
   ─┬───────                         
    │                ┌ сухогруз        -  Севастополь               
    │ ┌   корабль    ┤ ледокол         -  Ленин
    │ │              └ фрегат          -  Победа 
    │ │                               
    └─┤              ┌ село            -  Дубравино
      │              │ районный центр  -  Купавино
      │  Населенный  ┤ станица         -  Луганская
      └    пункт     │ город           -  Владимир
                     └ столица         -  Токио

          └─────┘      └───────┘         └────────────┘                 
                названия                     имена   
          └───────────────────────────────────────────┘
                            названия
```

Мы не говорим:

> ```
>  Название учителя Андрей Борисович
>  Название ребенка Кирилл
>  Название собаки Рекс
> ```

Мы говорим:

> ```
> Название города Томск | имя старинного русского города Тверь
> Название яхты Победа  | имя корабля ― «Восток»
> ```
>
> Examples with a context
>   (1) [название, корабли](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_tagging&out=normal&dpp=50&spd=10&seed=7028&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E0%E7%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=5&lex2=%EA%EE%F0%E0%E1%EB%FC&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=3&lex3=&gramm3=S&sem3=r%3Aconcr+%7C+%28t%3Ahum+%7C+t%3Ahum%3Aetn+%7C+t%3Ahum%3Akin+%7C+t%3Ahum%3Asupernat%29&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&lang=en) (2) [название, нас. пункты](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E0%E7%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=5&lex2=%E3%EE%F0%EE%E4&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=3&lex3=&gramm3=S&sem3=r%3Aconcr%20%7C%20%28t%3Ahum%20%7C%20t%3Ahum%3Aetn%20%7C%20t%3Ahum%3Akin%20%7C%20t%3Ahum%3Asupernat%29&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&lang=en) | (3) [имена, нас. пункты](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=random&out=normal&dpp=50&spd=10&seed=1254&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E8%EC%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=3&lex2=%E3%EE%F0%EE%E4&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=&gramm3=S&sem3=r%3Apropn+%26+t%3Atopon&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&lang=en), (4) [имена, корабли](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E8%EC%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=3&lex2=%EA%EE%F0%E0%E1%EB%FC&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=&gramm3=S&sem3=r%3Aconcr%20%7C%20%28t%3Ahum%20%7C%20t%3Ahum%3Aetn%20%7C%20t%3Ahum%3Akin%20%7C%20t%3Ahum%3Asupernat%29&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&lang=en)

Название придумывают или составляют, и затем дают как для целого класса предметов или явлений, так и для отдельных предметов. Когда мы произносим нарицательные имена вещей, мы фактически утверждаем, что этот предмет относится к данному классу.

Каждый элемент данного, названного класса, в свою очередь, может быть или поименован, или пронумерован уже существующими именами. Таким образом получают имена индивидуальные элементы Андрей, Борис, Владимир, ... и Первый, Второй, Третий ... .

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `имя` is used for people, and `название` is for inanimate things. However, `имя` can also be used for pet names (`собака по имени Шарик`), names of ships and aircraft (e.g. `крейсер с именем Аврора`), geographical locations such as cities, mountains, rivers and so on, (in programming) variable names (`имена переменных`).

Answer (score 0):

Название = designation. If you can't call something a "designation", then use имя.

Answer (score -1):

All of the answers given are correct.
Sometimes in Russian "название" is the "official form" of a name, whereas "имя" - is the "speaking form" of a name.

Answer (score -2):

Пропала собака по ***кличке*** Дружок.
Animals have neither "имя", nor "название". They are called by кличка.